# PGP library for C

Tags: c, public-key-encryption, pgp

I am developing an client server communication application in C. I want to encrypt the messages between then using some public key encryption. I found PGP (pretty good privacy) is a good policy. So is there any library available for embedding PGP with my application. I need key generation, text message encryption (maximum 1024 byte length text), message decryption.

Thanks in advance

Comment: PGP is a high-level message encryption framework. The lower-level cryptographic primitives on which it builds are implemented for example by OpenSSL, which provides more idiomatic network communication solutions than PGP that use the same cryptographic ideas nonetheless. For instance, SSL itself may just be your answer.

Comment: yes it is. I started using openssl. But here I am facing many problem. I will come to stackoverflow always whenever I am having trouble. Here is one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11046513/rsa-private-encrypt-always-fails. Please help me in that issue too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should take a look at [GPG](http://www.gnupg.org/related_software/libraries.html) (GNU alternative to PGP).

There also [GnuTLS](http://www.gnutls.org/) or well known [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/) library.

Comment: +1. No need to look any further.

Comment: Neither GnuTLS nor OpenSSL offer OpenPGP functionality.

Comment: I am currently writing a C library that utilizes Libsodium and SQLite to provide a full public-key infrastructure management solution - Libhermetik.